# Reshape the dataset into more relational format (Transpose SOME rows and assign them to a data subset)

Tags: json, regex, csv, vim, openrefine

I have a spreadsheet/csv:

```
Code:,101,Course Description:,"Introduction to Rocket Science",
Student Name,Lecture Hours,Labs Hours,Test Score,Status
John Galt,48,120,4.7,Passed
James Taggart,50,120,4.9,Passed
...
```

I need to reshape it to the following view:

```
Code:,Course Description:,Students,Lecture Hours,Labs Hours,Average Test Score,Teaching Staff
101,"Introduction to Rocket Science",John Galt,48,120,4.7,Passed
101,"Introduction to Rocket Science",James Taggart,50,120,4.9,Passed
...
```

Beleive it or not, can not get the right idea how to do that despite it seems to be *very primitive transformation*, is there any silver bullet for this?

Original records (csv) have in a way json-like structure so my first approach was to **represent the original data as a vector and then transpose it**, (but in this case my resulting table looks like sparced matrix - rows I have transpored are blank in the rest of its values)
Another way I`m considering - **serialize it into jsons and then de-serialize** into new spreadsheet (jsonize()) - in this case, I`m having problems with merging them properly.

In both ways I have it "half-working";
Can anyone suggest simple and reliable algorithm for this;
Any language, RegEx, any tools, code snippets are very appreciated

Comment: Your reshaped CSV is weird: the first row has seven columns and the second only six.

Comment: All rows in resulting dataset have 7 columns;

Comment: In the source dataset there are two attributes that have to be added as columns in the resulting dataset (Code and Course Description). So there are 5 columns in the source and 7 columns in the resulting one.

Comment: Yes, but in the first row of your reshaped example, there are tree variables after 48 (120, 4.7, passed) and only two in the second row after 50 (4.9, passed). This CSV is not well structured.

Comment: Yes, Etore, thanks, just missed one of vals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the pattern you've described here is consistent throughout, there are quite a few different approaches you could take I think, but in all cases you basically can use that fact that the 'Course' rows start with "Code:" but that's never going to be a student name.

You can take advantage of this either by a regular expression find/replace, or within OpenRefine.

Example:

1. Open file in a text editor that supports regular expressions in
   find/replace
2. Search for lines starting with 'Code:' and add additional commas to the start of the row to shift the course data columns to the
   right e.g. search for: ^Code:    replace with: ,,,,,^Code:
3. If you now import the file into OpenRefine then you'll have a project with 10 columns (the 10th col is caused by the trailing
   comma at the end of the course data row)
4. You can now use Transpose (or just rename) on the right-most columns which contain the course data, while leaving the left-most
   columns which contain the student details
5. Isolate the rows that contain the phrase 'Student Name' in the first column and remove them (via a filter or facet)
6. Move the Course Code/Description columns to the beginning of the project, and use the 'Edit Cells->Fill Down' option on each column to get the values repeated on all the relevant lines
7. Finally rename the columns as you want, remove any extraneous columns

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot, Owen. Simply move 2 "bad" columns aside, transpose them and fill down. Do you think it is possible to do all this steps with just regex in vim/emacs ?

Comment: Probably! e.g. in vim :1,$s/^Code:/,,,,,/g then :g/^Student Name/d. Not sure about the 'Fill down' step - definitely easier in OpenRefine I think. sed would probably do the job too